# How to clean and standardize words using R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have some data like:

```
data<-data.frame(comment=c('scan','scanned','SCANNED','scan and sent','FAXED','faxed to','faxed- pt'))


1          scan
2       scanned
3       SCANNED
4 scan and sent
5         FAXED
6      faxed to
7     faxed- pt
```

I'm wondering how to use R to clean the data into:

```
1  scanned
2  scanned
3  scanned
4  scanned
5    faxed
6    faxed
7    faxed
```

Thanks!!

Comment: As the rules and your dataset get more complicated, this is a non-trivial problem.  This is a great package for it though, https://github.com/trinker/termco (use `devtools::install_github` to get it). The 'Building the Model' section of the vignette should be everything you could possibly need.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to checkout the `stringdist` package, e.g.:

```
library(stringdist)

toMatch <- c('scan', 'scanned', 'SCANNED', 'scan and sent', 'FAXED', 'faxed to', 'faxed- pt')
possibleValues <- c("scanned", "faxed")

possibleValues[amatch(x = toMatch, table = possibleValues, maxDist = Inf)]
```

Returns:

```
[1] "scanned" "scanned" "scanned" "scanned" "faxed"   "faxed"   "faxed"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approximate matching using `agrepl` in both a **dplyr** and **data.table** approach.  Not too much different than solutions here but potentially less code:

```
comment <- c('scan', 'scanned', 'SCANNED', 'scan and sent', 'FAXED', 'faxed to', 'faxed- pt')

library(data.table)
data.table(comment)[, cleaned := ifelse(agrepl("fax", comment), "faxed", "scanned")][,]

library(dplyr)
data_frame(comment) %>%
    mutate(cleaned = ifelse(agrepl("fax", comment), "faxed", "scanned"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way to do it, but it depends on how dirty the rest of the data is. If there were any entries that include both `scan` and `fax`, this wouldn't work.

```
data<-data.frame(comment=c('scan','scanned','SCANNED','scan and sent','FAXED','faxed to','faxed- pt'))
data$cleaned <- tolower(data$comment)
data$cleaned <- ifelse(grepl("scan", data$cleaned), "scanned", data$cleaned)
data$cleaned <- ifelse(grepl("fax", data$cleaned), "faxed", data$cleaned)
```

This leaves you with:

```
R> data
        comment cleaned
1          scan scanned
2       scanned scanned
3       SCANNED scanned
4 scan and sent scanned
5         FAXED   faxed
6      faxed to   faxed
7     faxed- pt   faxed
```